# document.write( ) in jquery modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog, simplemodal

Hello following is my div of modal. when I open the modal without this piece of code `document.write( webcam.get_html(320, 240) );` then the modal opens up successfully but when i put the above mentioned code then it opens up the new page and shows the `document.write` content into that page. Kindly let me know how can i modify the following div so it shows the `document.write( webcam.get_html(320, 240) );` inside the modal. `webcam.get_html(320, 240)` is a command of jpegcam plugin that runs the webcam of the laptop or the like, I also even tried by putting simple text `document.write( "abcd");` and on opening the modal it shows  abcd on new page. Kindly help, Thanks,

```
<div style='display:none' id="modal-content">
     <script language="JavaScript">
        document.write( webcam.get_html(320, 240) );
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just do `$('#modal-content').text(webcam.get_html(320, 240));`?

Comment: document write will overwrite the **entire** DOM, it's not really the right tool to insert pieces of HTML, but to replace the entire document with new content, that's why it's called document.write.

Comment: @adeneo It's inline, so shouldn't the document be open? I'm kind of confused what the OP means anyways.

Comment: @Ian - actually you're right, it should be closed by the time it gets to a script tag inside an element. It's still not the right way to add content.

Comment: @adeneo Sorry, I meant to say **open**, not *closed* - re-read my minorly edited comment. If the `document.write` is inline HTML, the document should be open and it should "work". Of course, if this HTML is dynamically added, it's definitely too late and the DOM will be overwritten. I completely agree it's not the right way to add content, I wasn't trying to defend that, I'm just looking at the immediate setup

Comment: so how to write the above in any div html?

Comment: @Ian - Oh, I guess I copied your typo, but I got what you meant, and yes, as long as the document isn't written to after it's "done", document write should work -> http://jsfiddle.net/uEFq5/

Comment: @adeneo Haha okay, I thought you understood, but your words (and my words) didn't match up. Yeah, good example :)

Comment: @user2304394 - `document.getElementById('modal-content').innerHTML = 'stuff to add here';`. With jQuery you'd use jQuery methods.

Comment: @adeneo kindly post it answer so i can accept your answer thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoud use something other than `document.write`, like getting the actual element you're trying to add content to, and the insert the HTML into that :

```
document.getElementById('modal-content').innerHTML = 'stuff to add here';
```

jQuery version:

```
$('#modal-content').html('stuff to add here');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 document.getElementById('modal-content').innerHTML = 'stuff to add here';
```